# Why the route items in the route table(fetched via netlink socket) doesn't have netmask info?

Tags: linux, sockets, routes, netlink

I'm writing a program to find out which network interface is the best to connect to a specified target address.

Right now, I can get the route table via `netlink` socket APIs, but seems there is no netmask infos in it. I read the manual of `rtnetlink`, in all `rtattr` items, there is no netmask infos, just `RTA_DST`, `RTA_SRC`, `RTA_GATEWAY`... defined.

So, how to check out the netmask infos in route table? Just like we can see in `route -n` outputs.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you share your code : sachinites@gmail.com

Answer (score 6):

The prefix length associated with `RTA_DST` is in the `rtm_dst_len` field of the `rtmsg`, not in an `rtattr`. (I guess because it's a fixed-size field, unlike `RTA_DST`, which varies in size depending on the family.)

Comment: +1 but I guess there are other fixed length fields like RTA_METRICS etc. There must be another reason for this choice.